# Importing tensorflow tensors into tensorflow js

Tags: javascript, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I was hoping to load a tensor image (can also be numpy array) into tensorflow js as an input tensor. I was wondering if there was any possible way of accomplishing this. (I don't want to load the raw image, I want to load it after preprocessing done in python). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Numpy array can be serialized and saved to json

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(numpy_array.tolist(), f)
```

Once the data is saved to a json file, it can be retrieved in a js code

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8')

tf.tensor(data).print()
```